# THREE.js Copy from SphereBufferGeometry to BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, buffer, buffer-geometry

I have created a BufferGeometry to store a bunch of triangles (for later manipulation with a vertex shader). The vertice position coordinates and colors were generated randomly and added as arrays inside the bufferGeometry.attributes property. When used to make a mesh it worked fine.  here is the code:-

```
//... Buffer Geometry               
triangles = 500;
Bgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
Bgeometry.dynamic = true;

//... Bvertex_coords                
Bvertex_coords = new Float32Array( triangles * 3 * 3 );             
for ( var i = 0, l = triangles * 3 * 3; i < l; i += 3 ) 
{
    Bvertex_coords[ i     ] = Math.random() - 0.5;//... x
    Bvertex_coords[ i + 1 ] = 2*(Math.random() - 0.5);//... y
    Bvertex_coords[ i + 2 ] = Math.random() - 0.5;//... z
}               
Bgeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( Bvertex_coords, 3 ) );
```

Next I want to create a similar BufferGeometry but this time the triangles should be initially arranged into a spherical "surface".  So I created a "donor" SphereBufferGeometry with the appropriate configuration.

The idea was to then simply copy the relevant data from the donor SphereBufferGeometry into the BufferGeometry.

Here is the code I have been using:-

```
//... Buffer Geometries

////... new (r72) method - create a "donor" sphereBufferGeometry
var Cgeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 4, 4 );              
var num_Cgeom_pos_coords = Cgeometry.attributes.position.array.length;              
var num_Cgeom_vertices = num_Cgeom_pos_coords/3;

//...Dgeometry  
//... first make a plain buffer geometry 
//... then copies data from an existing BufferSphereGeometry
Dgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
Dgeometry.dynamic = true;
Dpos_coords       = new Float32Array( num_Cgeom_pos_coords );
Dpos_normals      = new Float32Array( num_Cgeom_pos_coords );
for ( var pc = 0; pc < num_Cgeom_pos_coords ; pc ++  )
{
  Dpos_coords[ pc ]    = Cgeometry.attributes.position.array[pc];
  Dpos_normals[ pc ]   = Cgeometry.attributes.normal.array[pc];
}                           
Dgeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( Dpos_coords, 3 ) );
Dgeometry.addAttribute( 'normal',   new THREE.BufferAttribute( Dpos_normals,3 ) );


Pack_of_Triangles_mesh_D = new THREE.Mesh( Dgeometry, Sphere_Ord_material);
```

For some reason when I copy from the SphereBufferGeometry to a BufferGeometry and make a mesh only a small fraction (about 20-25%?) of the triangles are actually plotted.

QUESTION

So my question is: What do I need to do to get all the triangles to plot?

UPDATE1

By contrast the following method works OK: (1) make a mesh with a SphereGeometry, (2) make a new BufferGeometry with .setFromObject(mesh) (3) copy from the previous BufferGeometry to a new BufferGeometry and use the latter to make a new mesh.  But this seems a long-winded approach.

UPDATE2

The following method also works OK when Cgeometry is a SphereBufferGeometry.

```
Dgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
Dgeometry.copy ( Cgeometry );
var num_Dgeom_pos_coords = Dgeometry.attributes.position.array.length;  
var num_D_geom_vertices = num_D_geom_pos_coords/3;
```

It seems that the original problem is due to indexing being used in a SphereBufferGeometry and no index being built by default in a new BufferGeometry.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way of copying the index from the SphereBufferGeometry to the new BufferGeometry.

I am a bit confused because I thought the idea of BufferGeomtry involved doing without indexing.